# Groovy's XmlParser loses CDATA indicator

Tags: xml, groovy, xml-parsing

I'm using Groovy's XmlParser's parseText method to parse an XML string and return an object (Node obj) for further upstream handling/manipulation.  However, the parse is stripping out any CDATA wrappers.

Example.

```
import groovy.xml.XmlUtil

String xmlString = """
<stuff>
<people><![CDATA[Person01
Person02
Person03]]></people>
</stuff>
"""

Node xmlParsed = new XmlParser().parseText( xmlString )

print xmlParsed.people

print "\n----\n"

print XmlUtil.serialize( xmlParsed )
```

Outputs:

```
[people[attributes={}; value=[Person01
Person02
Person03]]]
----
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><stuff>
  <people>Person01
Person02
Person03</people>
</stuff>
```

So you can see the CDATA is gone in the output.  I've tried this w/the latest stable Groovy (2.5.9) and 3.0.0-rc-3 w/the same results.

I have a lot of stable upstream code working with the Node object that XmlParser returns, so I'm hoping there is something else I can do to preserve the CDATA.  Otherwise, I have plenty of hacky ideas for this that'll most definitely gobble up performance!  ;)

Thanks for reading and for any ideas!  :)
Eric

Answer (score 0):

XmlParser and XmlSlurper lose track of the `<![CDATA[` sections when they parse the xml

There is an alternative though, Java's dom classes maintain CDATA, and Groovy provides a builder to parse Elements from a Reader, and a DOMCategory to give you gpath style navigation over the dom elements...

So you can do the following:

```
import groovy.xml.DOMBuilder
import groovy.xml.XmlUtil
import groovy.xml.dom.DOMCategory

String xmlString = """
<stuff>
<people><![CDATA[Person01
Person02
Person03]]></people>
</stuff>
"""

def xmlParsed = DOMBuilder.parse(new StringReader(xmlString)).documentElement

use(DOMCategory) {
    println xmlParsed.people.text()
    println '----'
}
print XmlUtil.serialize(xmlParsed)
```

Which maintains the CDATA:

```
Person01
Person02
Person03
----
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><stuff>

  <people>
    <![CDATA[Person01
Person02
Person03]]>
  </people>

</stuff>
```

Comment: Yep, I saw another question like mine that gave a solution like yours leveraging DOMBuilder.  However, my intention is/was to work with a Node object.  Maybe it's not possible.  Fortunately, I found another solution to my problem that is outside of my original question (i.e., I don't need CDATA after all).  Thanks for your comment!